# NsdChat Socket Connection Exception in android

Tags: android, sockets, serversocket

Hi
 I downloaded NsdCaht apps from http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html. When i try to connect two devices i am getting exceptions.

## Exception

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.144 (port 42289): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:225)
at com.example.android.nsdchat.ChatConnection$ChatClient$SendingThread.run(ChatConnection.java:215)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
```

Please give me idea...

Comment: Hmmm ... interesting. So I downloaded the NsdChat.zip and imported it in a new project. That went quick. Installed the app on two devices in the same network. But now I don't know what to do? Can you tell me wich buttons to click for the devices and what i will see if i do? As now nothing is happening.

Comment: By just waiting, clicking buttons and having seen many red lines in the logcat this suddenly started to work and chatting messages are transported. But after a while i can only send messages in one direction. Maybe this is while one device went to sleep for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error for quite some time after the discovery part was working. Then after some time suddenly it got connected and I was able to send the messages to other device. After the service broadcasting from two or more devices by pressing register , android renames some of the service to avoid the conflict for same name. Generally the service is named with a number in brackets in front of the original name eg. Nsdchat (90).
         As a result whenever you press the register button, a service with different name is registered and a new port is allotted to that service. This results in closure of the previous port but the previous service name is not unregistered till now. Thus other devices are able to see the previous service name and port associated with it , but cannot connect to it because the port is closed and thus gives the IOException, which is given when the host is not found. 
         So,try reconnecting to the network, restart the app, and press the register button just once so that each device will have one service, one Ip and one port which is open to connection.
Hope this helps.